# Bluetooth Low Energy- How to scan the devices and search for a specific characteristic?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a programme that scan all devices and after that we can select one of them and choose the characteristic to get the value.
What i want is different, i want to scan the devices and when i find one with a specific characteristic automatically connect to this device. It's possible?
Thanks

Comment: Can't you just scab as you have been, and check the characteristics for a match? You evidently already have a way to both scan, and get the characteristics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use advertisement data ( say a specific UUID in adv data) and then on the scanning side compare the UUID in the received advertisement data to initiate a connection. this can also be done with scan response data instead of advertisement data. This is not same as reading a characterstic from a GATT server, instead a different mechanism to identify the remote device before establishing a GATT connection.